# How to change balances from another contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, erc-20, contract-invocation

I want to change balances from another contract but it wont work

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;


interface ICounter {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external view returns (bool);
    function balances(address owner) external returns (uint);
}

contract MyContract {
    uint public theBalance;
    function incrementCounter(address _counter,uint value) external {
        theBalance = ICounter(_counter).balances(msg.sender);
        theBalance = value;
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint) {
        return ICounter(_counter).balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

Comment: A contract cannot access another contract storage directly. The only way to change the balances would be if the interface has an external function that allows modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the functions of another contract. As you have defined the interface and functions of your second contract you have to instantiate an object or reference to that second contract like

`ICounter counter = ICounter(address of second contract);`

then you can access its functions like

`theBalances = counter.balances(msg.sender);`